# Map ASP.NET MVC action parameter name to another name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, parameters, action

Can I map an action's parameter to a different name?

I want to use reserved words as parameters for an action, such as:

```
search?q=someQuery&in=location&for=x
```

So "in" and "for" can't be used as parameter names of the method.
Is there a built in feature for that or should I create a model binder?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the '@' notation to make the name be interpreted literally rather than a reserved word in c#.

```
public ActionResult Test(string @for)
{
    var something = @for;
}
```

Comment: Great. Thanks! Totally forgot about it (like @class in html attributes).
But what about mapping a query item like "in" to a parameter named "inLocation"? I might just create ActionParameterNameAttribute with usage like: [ActionParameterName("in")] inLocation.
Exactly like [ActionName] does for actions.

Comment: public ActionResult MyMethod([Bind(Prefix="in")] string inLocation) { ... }

Comment: @Arnis L. - What is wrong with the proposal?  Renaming parameters as suggested by elad.ossadon's comment is precisely one of the scenarios [Bind(Prefix=...)] was designed to cover.

Comment: Thank you so much that is really useful. I used it like this with great success: [Bind(Prefix="Product.Brand")]int brandId